Is negative delay (early arrival ) an actual delay
I'm creating a Tableau dashboard using the dataset '2015 Flight Delays and Cancellations' and trying to answer a question related to delays. I noticed that my delay columns have values ranging from -80 to 1900. I'm confused about whether, when summing or averaging these values, I should consider negative delays as actual delays and use the ABS function so that the negative and positive values don't cancel each other out or keep everythng as is.

You didn't describe the Business Domain problem your dashboard seeks to address.
A dashboard is a program.
It deserves a Requirements document
and an automated Test Suite like any other.
Else we can't tell if its output is buggy or is conformant to the spec.
If stakeholders are frequent travelers trying to predict
how much of their own time will be wasted at the departure airport,
then an airline with lots of early departures is one that
requires you to arrive at the airport earlier, or risk missing a flight.
This includes risk of being bumped by another traveler who arrived
at the gate long before you did.
If an airline's expected push-off time is ten minutes before the scheduled time,
then it could make sense to inflate all late departure delays by ten minutes
in the interest of "truth in advertising".
If stakeholders are frequent travelers trying to predict timeliness of
arrival at destination airport, then examining early departures may have
good explanatory value for understanding the distribution of arrival delays.
They would surely want to see an airline's reports of early arrivals,
even in cases where "favorable weather" was the best explanation.
If stakeholders are budgeting for the purchase of J-4 jet fuel (kerosene),
then trimming early departure figures to zero might make sense,
as the airline is only incented to wastefully fly faster (more drag)
when behind schedule.
Then again, early departure may permit flying at even slower than planned speed,
and such a stakeholder would want to preserve the amount of earliness.
At a minimum, your dashboard should accurately label the displayed quantities,
and reveal what filtering and pre-processing happened to the raw data before
display. If you choose to take ABS( ... ) of such latencies, then consider
using a label like "deviation" from schedule, rather than "delay".
